# How to construct a method that needs to pass in the values from a constructor?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

I'm writing a program that is based around registering the amount of energy consumption that is being used by appliances within a house. So far, I have created various meter classes such as WaterMeter, GasMeter etc. with empty methods that need to be filed with values, I have also created classes for appliances that have methods that will be used to register the consumption of energy within each appliance. What I am working on now is applying the energy values that are stored within a constructor, putting those values into a `timePasses()` method that will then return those values to their specific meter's methods so that they can be registered. This is what I have so far:

**Appliance class example:**

```
public class ElectricShower extends Shower
{

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int incrementTime;
    public int x = -1;

    private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();
    public static ElectricMeter getInstance() { return instance; }

     @Override
     public int currentState()
    {

        if (x == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
        {
            return isOn;
        }
        //returns isOn;
}

      @Override
        public void useTime(int defaultTime)
        {

            defaultTime = 15;
            incrementTime = 1;

        }

        public void shower()
        {

            //call timePasses() method

        }

        @Override
         public int timePasses()
         {

             if(x == isOff)
                 return 0;
             else
             {
             ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);             
             }

         }

    ElectricShower(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{
    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);


    this.electricityUse = 12 * incrementTime;
    this.gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.waterUse = 4 * incrementTime;
    this.timeOn = 15 * incrementTime;

} 

}
```

**Meter example:**

```
public class ElectricMeter 
{
public int incrementConsumed(int value)  
    {

    }

    public int incrementGenerated()  
    {

    }
    public boolean canGenerate()  
    {

    }
    public String getConsumed()  
    {

    }
    public String getGenerated()  
    {

    }

}
```

What I need to do next is:

1. take the values of `electricityUse` and `waterUse` and store them within the `timePasses()` else staement
2. Within the `timePasses()` else statement, place the value of `electrcityUse` in the `incrementGenerated()` method within the `ElectricMeter` class and do the same for the `waterUse` variable.

**UPDATE**

Classes have been updated, still struggling to find out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you have an `Appliance` class that all the appliances extends from. You should create variables in the `Appliance` class that stores electricity, gas and water usage:

```
public class Appliance
{
    public int electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn;
    // ...
}
```

Note that you should *always* use getters and setters instead of public fields. I'm just lazy :D

Change your constructor so that the variables above get set:

```
ElectricShower(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{
    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);
    // I don't know why you multiply the constant by incrementTime here. Seems weird. I think you can remove them.
    this.electricityUse = 12 * incrementTime;
    this.gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.waterUse = 4 * incrementTime;
    this.timeOn = 15 * incrementTime;

}
```

One way to write the `else` clause is to use the "Singleton Pattern".

In every meter class, write something like this:

```
private ElectricMeter() {}
private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();
public static ElectricMeter getInstance() { return instance; }
```

In the `incrementConsumed` method, you should accept a parameter that indicates how much to increment:

```
public int incrementConsumed(int value)  
{
    // logic here...
}
```

In the `else` clause, you can just do:

```
ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);
GasMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(gasUse);
WaterMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(waterUse);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I a little confused about the `private ElectricMeter() {}` line. Firstly what does this do? And secondly when I implement it I can an error saying the the constructor cannot be applied as it has no arguments and it requires int, int, int, int.

Comment: This is just to prevent other parts of code from creating instances of the meters. If you get that error, it seems that ElectricMeter inherits from a superclass. This only works if meters don't inherit from anything. @Tom

Comment: The meter classes do inherit from a super class called Meter. I've updated my classes within my question, still can't quite figure out how to make it work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You should put `private ElectricMeter() {}
private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();
public static ElectricMeter getInstance() { return instance; }` in every meter class. @Tom

Answer (score 0):

You should review your design.

If you need to access to a class parameter you could just define it *public* or better create a so called *getter* method that returns the value.

Example:

```
public class MyData {
    public int counter;
}

....
// Some other class
MyData data = new MyData();

data.counter = 5;

System.out.println(data.counter);
```

Or

```
public class MyData {
    private int counter;
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return this.counter;
    }
}

....
// Some other class
MyData data = new MyData();

data.setCounter(5);

System.out.println(data.getCounter());
```

In your code I see:

```
public int incrementConsumed()  
{
    //Store value of electricityUse.
}
```

But this method should just return an integer and have not parameter to get an input to store.

It should be:

```
public void incrementConsumed(int amount) {
    this.amount += amount;
}
```

I'm concerned about this line:

```
gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
```

If you multiply something to *0* it will be always *0*...